# Passing JSON requests one by one to REST API

Tags: python, json

I have created a json file form a csv file. This JSON file has multiple requests. I need to call REST API on these requests. How can I send these requests one by one to API for processing? I tried to search and everywhere I can see the syntax only for one requests. Not sure whether we can pass requests in bulk.

I am not sure how to pick one request from a file and pass it to API as POST method.
This is what I find in my search to pass POST request:

```
import requests

r=requests.post(url, data=<how to pass requests one by one here>)
```

I guess I need to parse this JSON file first. I can use something like this to parse it.

```
import json
with open('data.json') as file:
  data = json.load(file)
```

***sample json file :***
*data.json*

```
 [
        {
            "consumerData": {
                "clientCode": "CSP_CLINICAL", 
                "instance": "CSP-GFS", 
                "userId": ""
            }, 
            "gfsauthdata": [
                {
                    "Amt": "1000.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123545", 
                    "LineNo": "1", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA12"
                }, 
                {
                    "Amt": "200.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123545", 
                    "LineNo": "2", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA12"
                }, 
                {
                    "Amt": "200.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123545", 
                    "LineNo": "3", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA12"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "consumerData": {
                "clientCode": "CSP_CLINICAL", 
                "instance": "CSP-GFS", 
                "userId": ""
            }, 
            "gfsauthdata": [
                {
                    "Amt": "200.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123546", 
                    "LineNo": "1", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA13"
                }, 
                {
                    "Amt": "200.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123546", 
                    "LineNo": "2", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA13"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "consumerData": {
                "clientCode": "CSP_CLINICAL", 
                "instance": "CSP-GFS", 
                "userId": ""
            }, 
            "gfsauthdata": [
                {
                    "Amt": "200.00", 
                    "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "Id": "123547", 
                    "LineNo": "1", 
                    "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", 
                    "regionId": "WA14"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is a design decision. Ideally, you should create an endpoint that can support both bulk processing and individual requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the top elements of your list are the "requests", so this piece of code should get you started

```
import json
import requests
with open('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for element in data:
        r=requests.post(url, json=element)
        r.raise_for_status() # Add this line to make sure requests succeeded
```